# Why does my python code not edit a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, text, file-handling

I am making a stock app, and so far everything is going smooth. However, when running the code, towards the end, once I buy shares, nothing happens. My text file containing my user data doesn't get edited, and I am left with code that works but doesn't save. How can I fix this?

My code:

```
import requests as req
from tkinter import *
import json
import os
import ast
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
from datetime import date
#Login Is Admin, Pwd is Admin123

def main(username):
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('500x500')
  Label(root, text = "Hello! Do you want to view stocks, view your money, or quit?", font = ('arial bold', 14 ), underline = True).pack()
  resbox = Text(root)
  resbox.pack()
  def get_data():
    response = resbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    if response.lower() == 'view stocks':
      root.destroy()
      get_stocks(username)
    elif response.lower()=='view money':
      root.destroy()
      root1 = Tk()
      Label(root1, text=stats['Money'],font=('arial bold',20)).pack()
    elif response.lower() == 'quit':
      root.destroy()
      print("Goodbye!")
  Button(root, text = "Enter Response!", command = get_data, background = 'salmon').pack()
def get_stocks(username):
  root2 = Tk()
  root2.geometry('500x500')
  inputbox = Text(root2, padx = 40, pady = 30)
  inputbox.pack()
  name = ""
  def search_function():
    name = inputbox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    root2.destroy()
    layout(name.upper())
  
  search = Button(root2, text = "Search Info", background = "gray", command = search_function).pack()
  
  def layout(name):
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.geometry('500x500')
    info = req.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=' + name + '&count=5&token=[RESTRICTED_API_KEY]&resolution=D&from=' + str(date.today()) + '&to=' + str(date.today()))
    info1 = req.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=' + name + '&token=[RESTRICTED_API_KEY]')
    data = info.json()
    data1 = info1.json()
    vol_len = len(data['v'])
    vol = data['v'][vol_len - 1]
    price = data1['c']
    percent = data1['dp']
    if percent < 0:
        fg = 'red'
    elif percent > 0:
        fg = 'green'
    elif percent == 0:
        fg = 'gray'
    title_widget = Label(root1, text = name, font = ("arial bold", 50), underline = True).pack()
    vol_widget = Label(root1, text = str(vol) + " in total.", font = ("arial bold", 40)).pack()
    price_widget = Label(root1, text = str(price) + " dollars per share.", font = ("arial bold", 30)).pack()
    percent_widget = Label(root1, text = str(percent) + "%", font = ("arial bold", 20), fg = fg).pack()
    try:
      if type(stats[name]) == "int":
        stats["Money"] += data1['d'] * stats[name]
        sell_shares = Text(root1, height = 5)
        sell_shares.pack()
        def sell():
          share_amount = sell_shares.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
          share_amount = int(share_amount)
          if share_amount > stats[name]:
            print("You don't have that many shares.")
          elif share_amount == stats[name]:
            stats["Money"] += share_amount * price
          elif share_amount < stats[name]:
            stats[name] -= share_amount
            stats["Money"] += share_amount * price
          with open(username + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(stats))
            f.close()
        Button(root1, text = "Sell shares", command = sell).pack()
      else:
        share_amount = Text(root1, height = 5)
        share_amount.pack()
        def buy_shares():
          shares = share_amount.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
          shares = int(shares)
          cost = shares * price
          if cost <= stats["Money"]:
            print("You have purchased " + str(shares) + " shares.")
            stats[name] = shares
            root1.destroy()
            with open(username + '.txt', 'w') as f:
              f.write(str(stats))
              f.close()
          else:
            print("You do not have enough money to buy this.")
        Button(root1, command = buy_shares, text = "Buy shares").pack()
      if price > 500:
        Label(root1, text = "Definitely consider investing because the earnings you would get is phenomenal!").pack()
      elif price > 100:
        if percent > 1:
          Label(root1, text = "You may want to consider investing, because the earnings are decent and the stock may go up much more soon.").pack()
        elif percent < 1:
          Label(root1, text = "Think about how much people would need this product depending on the time, because this stock may fall and cause turmoil in your credit card.").pack()
      else:
        Label(root1, text = "You may not want to invest in this stock because it stands quite low now, and you may want to invest in it later, if it grows.")
    except KeyError:
      share_amount = Text(root1, height = 5)
      share_amount.pack()
      def buy_shares():
        shares = share_amount.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
        shares = int(shares)
        cost = shares * price
        if cost <= stats["Money"]:
          print("You have purchased " + str(shares) + " shares.")
          root1.destroy()
          with open(username + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(stats))
            f.close()
        else:
          print("You do not have enough money to buy this.")
      Button(root1, command = buy_shares, text = "Buy shares").pack()
    if price > 500:
      Label(root1, text = "Definitely consider investing because the earnings you would get is phenomenal!").pack()
    elif price > 100:
      if percent > 1:
        Label(root1, text = "You may want to consider investing, because the earnings are decent and the stock may go up much more soon.").pack()
      elif percent < 1:
        Label(root1, text = "Think about how much people would need this product depending on the time, because this stock may fall and cause turmoil in your credit card.").pack()
    else:
      Label(root1, text = "You may not want to invest in this stock because it stands quite low now, and you may want to invest in it later, if it grows.")

loginAttempts=5
openacc=input("Welcome to our CAC coding project! This project was made by Rian Chadha, Anakin Dasgupta, and Sid Burra.\nDo you have an account? (Y or N) ")
if openacc.lower()=='y':
  login=input("What is your username? \n>")
  if os.path.isfile(login + '.txt'):
    askPassword = input('What is your password?  \n>')
    
    with open(login + '.txt') as f:
        data = f.read()
        stats = ast.literal_eval(data)
    while not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(askPassword, stats['Password']) and loginAttempts > 0:
        print('Wrong password')
        loginAttempts -= 1
        askPassword = input('What is your password?  \n>')
    else:
        if loginAttempts <= 0:
            print('Too many failed tries. Please reload')
            exit()
        else:
          print('Logged in!')
          main(login)
  else:
    print("We couldn't find your account. Please try again. ")
    exit()
elif openacc.lower()=='n':
    print('Welcome!')
    stats = {'Money':1000, 'lastPayment': date.today()}

    newuser = input('What would you like your user name to be?\n>')
    while True:
        if newuser == 'no':
            print('Sorry, this name cannot be used.')
            newuser = input('What would you like your user name to be?  \n>')
        elif os.path.isfile(newuser + '.txt'):
            a = input(
                'This name is in use. Do you have an account? (Yes or no) \n>')
            if a.lower() == 'yes':
                print('Please reload.')
                exit()
            elif a.lower() == 'no':
                newuser = input(
                    'What would you like your user name to be?  \n>')
        else:
            break

    name = open(str(newuser) + '.txt', 'w')
    stats.__setitem__('User', (newuser))
    pwd = input('What would you like your password to be? \n>')
    pwd= pbkdf2_sha256.hash(pwd)
    stats.__setitem__('Password', pwd)
    name.write(str(stats) + '\n\n')
    print('Adding...\n')
    name.close()
    print(
        'Thank you for creating an account! Please reload, then try to log in.'
    )
    exit()

else:
    print(
        'There was an error logging in. Please reload, or your information will not be saved.'
    )
    exit()
```

My code returns no errors, it just doesn't save the data and write to the file. Pay most attention to the `with open(username + '.txt') as f:` parts because that is the one that doesn't run like it should.

Comment: Are you aware that opening a file in `w` mode will delete the contents of anything that was stored there previously? If you want to *append* data you should use `a` as mode instead of `w`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I am aware of that, and yes, that is my intent.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I.e a program that we can run, that shows what `stats` is, tries to write to a file, and doesn't work.

Comment: You've posted far too much code. Please try to create a [mcve] specifically for this question.

Comment: @ProgramProdigy I was asking because from your question it's not clear what you are asking. Before spending hours debugging we need to know if the "simple" causes are to be excluded.. a lot of users use `w` thinking it will append data and are surprised, so your "user data doesn't get edited" could simply have been that you expected to see more than one line of text.